# Assigning the output of {% include %} to a variable in Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a template that calls a sub template using {% include %}. I want to assign the rendered output of the subtemplate to a variable in outer template to further modify it with filters.

I get a syntax error if I do the following

Example

```
Outer_template
    blah
    blah
    ## set expanded_inner_template = {% include "inner_template" %}
    {{ expanded_inner_template|somefilter }}

(Syntax Error: unexpected '%)
```

Is there any way to assign the rendered output of sub-template to a variable in outer template for further processing

Comment: This looks like something you probably want to factor out into your view rather than doing within template processing.

Comment: the inner template is not in my control, I want to fetch the latest inner template everytime I expand my template. So changes in inner template would automatically be reflected in the outer template whenever I render the outer template

Answer (score 4):

I was in need of something similar and come across your question.

Since you said:

> to further modify it with filters.

It does not answer your question directly, but if all you want is to modify it in-place with filters, there are [filter sections](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#id11).

```
{% filter somefilter %}
    {% include "inner_template" %}
{% endfilter %}
```